# Updating CoreData and UINavigationController stacks

Tags: ios, core-data, uinavigationcontroller, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a storyboard that looks like this:

Summary List -> Recursive Table View -> Item View

It is managed by a navigation controller and for the best part works fine and as I'd expect. I can edit data without issue in the summary list:

```
Summary List -> Recursive Table View -> Item View
  |
  | <- (make a change here, use beginUpdate and endUpdate)
  |
Core Data
```

This bit works fine...

What should happen is that when one gets to the Item View the core data objects are updated and Item View will then appear on the next load of the summary list.

However, for some reason Summary List is still being refreshed in the background, I assume because it's in the navigation hierarchy, and therefore when I update the CoreData objects at the Item View board I get the classic 'CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent' - normally I would address this by ensuring I'd called beginUpdate and endUpdate but how do I do that if there might be a number of tableviews between me and the tableView in question?

This bit does not work:

```
Summary List -> Recursive Table View -> Item View
  |                                         |
  |                                         | > (a change here modifies the core
  |                                              data database, Summary List is
  |                                              still somehow loaded and error)
  |
Core Data
```

The full error is the classic 'you've done it wrong':

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was
caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call
to -controllerDidChangeContent:
Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.
The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update
(0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section
before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or 
deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus
the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
```

Comment: Can you give the full text of the error?

Comment: added now, but it's just the normal one...

Comment: Details matter. The row and section numbers and counts, and the type of operation, all help to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: So, this thinks that an item has been removed somehow from section 1 (the second section) of a table view. Do you know which one this is? Why would an item disappear from this section? Which parts of your code may be responsible here?

Comment: I know why it's been removed - what I don't know is how to tell an off-screen view controller to prepare for the updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've set the tables up with a fetched results controller in the standard manner, I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter if the table is on screen or not. It sounds like some unusual updates are being done and/or you're not using the fetched results controller as a datasource properly.

If you're having problems, you can turn off tracking by setting the fetched results controller's delegate to `nil`. Try this when the view goes offscreen, and restore (and reload the table) when it comes back.

Note that the exception you're seeing *isn't* due to missing begin and endUpdates calls. If they were missing, you wouldn't get the exception. They are happening, but inside there you don't have a match between the inserts/deletes and final row count. Before the beginUpdates you have a row in section 1, after you don't, and during you don't delete anything.

Comment: thanks, I'll try setting the delegate to nil as you suggest, however I can categorically tell you that I'm not calling beginUpdate and endUpdate - I'll try and update the question to provide more clarification

Comment: If you're using a fetched results controller, you really ought to be using begin and end updates. What are you doing in your FRC delegate methods?

Comment: but when should I? when the initial view controller disappears?

Comment: So a slightly weird thing here - if I use both begin/end in viewDidDissapear/willAppear then it breaks, if I JUST use end in appear then it works :-/

Comment: marked as answer as it's certainly what got me there!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your fetched results controller delegate methods. In the delegate callbacks, make sure you delete and add the appropriate number of cells and sections. Then this error will surely vanish.

Comment: No, it's not that. Updating the data directly works because I implement the begin and end Update method alls. The problem occurs because the view controller is still active on the stack while I'm changing core data - how do you tell a view controller that's not active that you're starting an update?

Comment: Handle it in `viewWillAppear`. Just reload before the view gets shown.

Comment: So a slightly weird thing here - if I use both begin/end in viewDidDissapear/willAppear then it breaks, if I JUST use end in appear then it works :-/

Comment: There is no need to do begin/end. They are only for animation. The view is not on screen, so you do not need animation.

Comment: If I do not do 'end' as I have described I get an exception.